# Why is this jquery extension not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, n2cms

I have this extension function and it seems to be not causing any problems. But as soon as I try to *use* it, I get an error message: Object doesn't support property or method 'n2name'

[image: Screenshot of the error]

No errors are reported in the plug-in code (snippet pasted below for reference, with a link to the full file at the end).

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Note: I'm trying to fix an issue on this open-source project: https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/issues/279 and there may be more useful details on that Github bug.

Sorry if this question is too vague, and for the long code snippet (most of it probably isn't relevant). But any help would really be appreciated

```
/**
* n2name 0.2
*/

(function($) {

    /* some code removed for brevity */

    $.fn.n2name = function(options) {
        var invokeUpdateName = function(){
            updateName(options.titleId, options.nameId, options.whitespaceReplacement, options.toLower, options.replacements, options.keepUpdatedBoxId);
        };
        if(options.keepUpdatedBoxId){
           /* more code removed for brevity */
        }
    };
})(jQuery);;
```

Link to jquery.n2name.js full source, if the code snippet above is not useful: https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/blob/4469580fcdd9c91f7576f07c3d2c8a4479ed6ce9/src/Mvc/MvcTemplates/N2/Resources/Js/plugins/jquery.n2name.js

Comment: It seems like you're calling  `$().n2name()` before the plugin is loaded into the page (or it is not being loaded at all).

Comment: This `jquery.n2name.js` (where the above script is defined) is getting included in `<head>` right after jquery-1.9.1-min.js and jquery-ui. The call that's failing is in a `<script>` tag right before `</body>`. Would that confirm your suspicion?

Comment: Make sure that there's no `defer`/`async` attribute on the plugin script tag and that its path is correct and that there are no loading errors - or just open the console and type `jQuery.fn.n2name` to see whether it is actually loaded.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much! It looks like my copy of Visual Studio is having trouble loading the resources from http://localhost for some reason (the HTTP request is showing as "Cancelled" in the script debugger). When I uploaded it to the web server, it worked. Strange... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors "Object doesn't support property or method `<name>`" (IE) and "`<name>` is not a function" (Chrome) usually mean that your jQuery plugin didn't successfully load before it was called.

This can be due to a failed request (check Dev Tools' Network tab), forgetting/misplacing the plugin's `script` tag or the `script` tag having `defer`/`async` attributes. Another possible cause is the plugin's script containing syntax errors (check the Dev Tools' Console tab in that case).

Having multiple versions of jQuery in the same page (as commented in OP's linked GH issue) is another possibility, seeing as plugins wrapped in the `(function(){}(jQuery));` boilerplate are only added to the jQuery object referenced by `window.jQuery` at the time the plugin script loads.

---

In this specific case, OP was having issues to load the plugin from localhost inside VS.

I've seen similar issues, and I'll just add that it is invalid to use protocol-less URLs (for example: `//somecdn.com/library.js`) when loading files from a `file:///` URI scheme. This is because protocol-less URLs "inherit" the protocol being used from the parent document and `file:///` is not a protocol. In case you're loading it from a local server (e.g. parent document served through `http` as in `http://localhost/library.js`) the protocol-less URLs should work fine.